# How to use radio buttons in a table that is retrieved from the database and store the value in another table

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am trying to make an attendance chart in php.
i wish to increment the counter of attendance in the database on click of a radio button.
how do i retrieve the value and then increment for every "yes"?

do i need to put the updation code in the next page?

i tried it that way..but the fields are not getting updated..

```
if($class=="cse")
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cse");
        echo "<table border=15px cellspacing=40>";
        echo "<tr><th>NAME</th><th>BUPIN</th><th>ATTENDANCE</th></tr>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row["bupin"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type='radio' name='presence[".$row["bupin"]."]' value='yes'>Yes";
        echo "<input type='radio' name='presence[".$row["bupin"]."]' value='no'>No" . "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
    <html>
    <form action= "final6.php" method="POST">
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </html>
    }}
```

and the next page code is as:`if (isset($_POST["presence"])) 
    {
        foreach ($presence as $key => $val) 
        {
        if ($val == 'yes') 
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE cse SET 1attendance = 1attendance + 1 WHERE bupin = " .$key;
            msyqli_query($con, $sql);
        }
        }
    }
    echo "Attendance marked successfully..";
}`

where am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the bupin the primary key (id) in your table `cse`, then try this. Of course, change the `field` in the query to your field, what you want to incrase.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cse");
echo "<table border=15px cellspacing=40>";
echo "<tr><th>NAME</th><th>BUPIN</th><th>ATTENDANCE</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row["bupin"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='radio' name='presence[".$row["bupin"]."]' value='yes'>Yes";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='presence[".$row["bupin"]."]' value='no'>No" . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";


if (isset($_POST["presence"])) {
    foreach ($presence as $key => $val) {
        if ($val == 'yes') {
            $sql = "UPDATE cse SET field = field + 1 WHERE bupin = " . $key;
            msyqli_query($con, $sql);
        }
    }
}
```